# Killing gentile under threat of death

Tags: halacha, gentiles, pikuachnefesh-danger-life, murder

If someone points a gun at Reuvein's head and tells him, *"Kill this Jew or I'll kill you,"* the *halachah* is that Reuvein must let himself be killed. What if someone points a gun at Reuvein's head and tells him, *"Kill this non-Jew or I'll kill you."*

What is the *halachah* in that scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what the Halocho is regarding killing a non Jew. The texts have all been censored to make them PC.

The Rambam in [הלכות רוצח ושמירת נפש - פרק שני](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_02035.html#HtmpReportNum0050_L2) says:

> **יא** בָּרִאשׁוֹנָה מִי שֶׁהָרַג גֵּר תּוֹשָׁב אֵינוֹ נֶהֱרָג עָלָיו בְּבֵית דִּין שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (שמות כא-יד) 'וְכִי יָזִד אִישׁ עַל רֵעֵהוּ'. **וְאֵין צָרִיךְ לוֹמַר שֶׁאֵינוֹ נֶהֱרָג עַל הָעַכּוּ''ם**. ‏

The Kesef Mishneh then adds:

> **ישראל שהרג גר תושב וכו'.** במכילתא וכי יזיד איש על רעהו רעהו להוציא את אחרים ומשמע לרבינו דגר תושב בכלל אחרים כמו שהוא לענין גלות כמו שיתבאר. איסי בן עקיבא אומר קודם מתן תורה היינו מוזהרים על שפיכות דמים לאחר מתן תורה שהוחמרו הוקלו **באמת אמרו פטור מדיני בשר ודם ודינם מסור לשמים**. ‏

It would appear that a Jew *only* gets a heavenly, but not a corporeal, punishment for killing a non-Jew.

In that case it doesn't seem he'd be allowed to choose to get killed rather than kill the non-Jew.

---

After further research:

According to the Gemara in [Pesachim (25b)](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00880.html#HtmpReportNum0047_L2) the reason for getting killed rather then killing is because of מאי חזית דדמא דידך סומק טפי דילמא דמא דההוא גברא סומק טפי  - who says your blood is redder than his.

Rashi there explains:

> **מאי חזית דדמא דידך סומק.** כלומר, כלום באתה לישאל על כך אלא מפני שאתה יודע שאין מצוה  עומדת בפני פיקוח נפש, וסבור אתה שאף זו תדחה מפני פיקוח נפשך, אין זו דומה לשאר עבירות דמ''מ יש כאן אבוד נפש, והתורה לא התירה לדחות את המצוה אלא **מפני חיבת נפשו של ישראל** וכאן עבירה נעשית ונפש אבודה. מי יאמר שנפשך חביבה לפני המקום יותר משל זה? דילמא של זה חביבה טפי עליו! ונמצא עבירה נעשית ונפש אבודה. ‏

Rashi explicitly says 'how do you know that Gcd prefers your life more than the other **Jew's** life?

And again in [Yoma (82b)](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00882.html#HtmpReportNum0161_L2):

> **מאי חזית דדמא דידך סומק טפי**. כלומר מאי דעתיך למשרי מילתא משום *וחי בהם ולא שימות בהם*? טעמו של דבר לפי **שחביבה נפשן של ישראל לפני המקום** יותר מן המצות. אמר הקב''ה ת*בטל המצוה ויחיה זה*! אבל עכשיו שיש כאן ישראל נהרג והמצוה בטילה למה ייטב בעיני המקום לעבור על מצותו? למה יהיה דמך חביב עליו יותר מדם חבירך **ישראל**:.‏

Here Rashi mentions twice that מאי חזית is referring to Jews only.

Comment: It is a speculative leap to say that *yeihareig v'al ya'avor* doesn't apply because there is "only" a divine death penalty for killing a non-Jew.

Comment: @Fred - it's not clear which of these sentences were written for self-preservation, and which are Halacha. But even at face value, to require one to give up one's life for an action that Bet Din would ignore, is difficult to justify. (Note that in these Halachot there is nothing as explicit as what is in Hilchot Geneiva: וְאָסוּר לִגְזל כָּל שֶׁהוּא דִּין תּוֹרָה אֲפִלּוּ עַכּוּ''ם  אָסוּר לְגָזְלוֹ אוֹ לְעָשְׁקוֹ. וְאִם גְּזָלוֹ אוֹ עֲשָׁקוֹ יַחְזִיר:)

Comment: Self-preservation? The *Kesef Mishneh* is quoting the *Mechilta* (*Mishpatim*): איסי בן עקיבא אומר קודם מתן תורה היינו מוזהרים על שפיכות דמים לאחר מתן תורה תחת שהוחמרו הוקלו? באמת אמרו פטור מדיני בשר ודם ודינו מסור לשמים. Regardless, your answer doesn't address מאי חזית, which is the basis of *yeihareig v'al ya'avor*.

Comment: @Fred - see the additions to my answer. (And thanks for helping me find it.)

Comment: This Rashi is not dispositive. For example, if the choice was "kill him or I kill you both" a strict read of this Rashi would say "kill him" because he is dead either way, so you are at least saving yourself. However, the Rambam doesn't pasken that way WRT a whole city. So it could be that Rashi is explaining up to a point, but not giving the full extension of the principle, or it could be that Rashi disagrees with the Rambam, and the Rambam may say it applies to a non-Jew. Pinging @Fred, just because you are there.

Comment: There's a lot more to the סברא of מאי חזית וכו׳ that isn't in Rashi- it's discussed by the first piece in Reb Chaim. And as per @Fred, the Meshech Chochma there (Shemos 21:14) writes that the idea that דינו מסור לשמים means killing the non-Jew is **even worse** that killing a Jew

Comment: "to require one to give up one's life for an action that Bet Din would ignore, is difficult to justify." This is not so. Many Achronim hold that even Abizrayhu of the "big 3" are Yeihareg v'al Ya'avor even though they do not get capital punishment or even any punishment.

Comment: @Matt Just to mention this explicitly, the *Meshech Chochma* implies (IIRC) that there is a two-fold divine death penalty for murdering a non-Jew: one for murder and the other for *chilul HaShem*. Since the violator's eventual death would only satisfy the punishment for *chilul HaShem*, it is left to Heaven to impose on the violator's soul an alternative punishment to the theoretical divine death penalty for murder. (I suppose this is against the opinion of R' Nechunya ben Hakana regarding קם ליה בדרבה מיניה on [*K'suvos* 30a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=15&daf=30&format=text)).

Comment: @Matt According to Reb Chaim's preferred understanding of מאי חזית as involving mutually counteracting פיקוח נפש, it could be that considerations of איבה would counteract the Jew's פיקוח נפש and thus remove any justification for רציחה of the non-Jew.

Comment: @Fred - What kind of Chillul Hashem would there be in this case for Reuvein? (someone points a gun at Reuvein's head and tells him, "Kill this non-Jew or I'll kill you."). As to divine punishment why doesn't אונס רחמנא פטריה kick in?

Comment: Again requesting the removal of the Rambam as it doesnt directly address the question. Noteworthy is the Raavan (IIRC) who says that the prohibition of retzicha exists even b non-Jews, just not the penalty of death.

Comment: @DannySchoemann I only brought up *Chilul HaShem* tangentially; I doubt it's a critically relevant factor here. As far as אונס רחמנא פטריה, that doesn't tell you what a person *should* do in such a case; it merely exculpates somebody who lacked the moral fortitude to do what they were supposed to do when being coerced under threat of death (assuming it applies in this case).

Answer (score 5):

In shut bney banim volume 3 , 42-45 rabbi henkin addresses this and concludes it's prohibited to kill the non Jew