Where does the Torah prohibit the killing of non-Jews?
Please provide one Halachic or other source from the Torah that prohibits Jews killing gentiles. The Rambam doesn't say it. Sanhedrin 57a even says a Jew who kills a gentile is exempt. The posuk that prohibits murder, Genesis 9:6, even uses the verbiage of Adam, which suggests the prohibition is to murder limits to Jews. It looks like the only prohibition for killing non-Jews is the government and the laws of the land. Otherwise it would be to keep the peace so that Jews aren't harmed. But a primary prohibition of killing gentiles? Non-existent. Please show me otherwise.
EDIT: Mishna Sanehdrin 4:5 refers to HaAdam as Jews - "Therefore, Adam the first man was created alone, to teach you that with regard to anyone who destroys one soul from the Jewish people, i.e., kills one Jew, the verse ascribes him blame as if he destroyed an entire world, as Adam was one person, from whom the population of an entire world came forth. And conversely, anyone who sustains one soul from the Jewish people, the verse ascribes him credit as if he sustained an entire world."
“You are called Adam, but the nations of the world are not called Adam” [Yevamos 61a; Bava Metzia 114b; Kerisus 6b].

Kill or murder?

I've edited out a part of your post that definitely gave the impression you were making a point rather than asking a question.

Why do you think its forbidden on a torah level?

Don't edit my post. The point should be made clearly that there is no primary prohibition to kill non-Jews. We may be forbidden because of chillul HaShem or derech shalom or dina d'malchusa dina, but the Torah doesn't care directly about Jews taking non-Jewish lives. Prove me wrong

possible dupe https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/132336/no-halacha-to-punish-jews-for-this-crime https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/80102/is-killing-a-gentile-also-forbidden-with-the-%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%95-of-%D7%9C%D7%90-%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%A6%D7%97 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/136433/does-the-gemara-teach-that-jews-are-allowed-to-kill-gentiles-but-not-vice-versa

I'm not sure why you impute feeling/sense to the Torah ("the Torah doesn't care...").

TY. The will of G-d is reflected in the Halacha.

great! Then His will is made clear in the halachic sources https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/134281/clarification-on-quotation-sources-around-sanhedrin-57a/134283#134283

None of the above actually answers the claims. Ger Toshav as an identity doesn't exist today as it requires a formal designation before a court. That still leaves the rest of humanity only protected under secular law from Jews

Your latter post is helpful. Thanks

You answer well. I wish I could subscribe to you

The sources available online on the prohibition from killing non-Jews is scant. I searched via the help of AI all the Halachic corpi available to me and all I can find is one Midrashic commentary. At least it would indicate that it's mideroisa since it is derived directly from a posuk. But consequences? The actual death penalty stipulated? No explanation. It's good start though, BH

These topics, as well as relevant background, have been discussed and answered elsewhere on this site, including: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/134283/ https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/80102/ https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/74049/ https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/89420/ https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/132336/ and the comments on https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/49173/

possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/80102/759

And as for the quote about where the word "adam" is used in reference to Jews -- focus specifically on the legal contexts in which the Talmud uses it -- it's never about murder.  See more at https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/31058/21


Please provide one Halachic or other source from the Torah that prohibits Jews killing gentiles. The Rambam doesn't say it.

This false. The Rambam Rotzeach 1:1 says כָּל הוֹרֵג נֶפֶשׁ בֶּן אָדָם עוֹבֵר בְּלֹא תַּעֲשֶׂה
Whoever a person kills a human being,  transgresses a negative commandment
Ben Odom means all people.

Sanhedrin 57a even says a Jew who kills a gentile is exempt.

There is no requirement for the  death penalty for a Jew who kills a non-Jew. Similarly, a non-Jewish court is not obligated to give the death penalty to a non-Jew who kills a Jew. Murder is still 100% prohibited in both cases. In general the question  seem to be confusing lack of the death penally with permissiblity

The posuk that prohibits murder, Genesis 9:6, even uses the verbiage of Adam, which suggests the prohibition is to murder limits to Jews.

Pretty off base assumption considering that this posuk  is actually (also) addressed to non-Jews (as per the very Gemora quoted above) . There were no Jews at the time. The  posuk  in the Torah that prohibits murder for Jews is   לֹא  תִרְצָח

It looks like the only prohibition for killing non-Jews is the government and the laws of the land.

All of  the classic halakhic authorities agree that it is forbidden for a Jew to murder a non-Jew, there is some debate as to where it is learned from.

כל הורג נפש אדם מישראל--עובר בלא תעשה https://mechon-mamre.org/i/b501.htm#1 You're probably being fooled by a censored version

"Murder is still 100% prohibited in both cases." You've elided the distinction between derabanan and deorayta prohibitions. It seems to me the OP was specifically seeking deorayta issues.

@DoubleAA OP doesn't specify duraysa only. Rabbanan laws are often more strict than duraysa anyways so a distinction shouldn't matter

Regarding Sanhedrin 4:5: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/74049/anyone-who-saves-a-life-is-as-if-he-saved-an-entire-world-jewish-life-or-any

Interesting that the first halacha of Rambam clearly can only be referring to a yid/eved since 2:10 states:  "At first, a person who killed a resident alien should not be executed by the court, as implied by Exodus 21:14, which introduces the laws regarding the punishment for murder, by stating: "When a man acts intentionally against his colleague, killing him...." Needless to say, this ruling applies with regard to a gentile...." So the first law, giving capital punishment, can't mean that. What's the actual source that it's prohibited?

@Awtsmoos--עצמות He didn't say it explicitly but it's implied in a number of his remarks. And we all know the distinction matters in numerous ways, you're not fooling anyone.

The source in the Rambam is 4:11 @Awtsmoos--עצמות

@ba fair enough. But the that should be mentioned in an answer. Also it doesn't mention the nature of the prohibition, it can't be for the same reasoning as 1:1. Also it seems to only refer to an idolater. What about a Ben Noach? Doesn't say explicitly

I don't know how but you are really going out of your way to misread Genesis 9:5-6

ה  וְאַךְ אֶת-דִּמְכֶם לְנַפְשֹׁתֵיכֶם אֶדְרֹשׁ, מִיַּד כָּל-חַיָּה
אֶדְרְשֶׁנּוּ; וּמִיַּד הָאָדָם, מִיַּד אִישׁ אָחִיו--אֶדְרֹשׁ,
אֶת-נֶפֶשׁ הָאָדָם. ו  שֹׁפֵךְ דַּם הָאָדָם, בָּאָדָם דָּמוֹ
יִשָּׁפֵךְ:  כִּי בְּצֶלֶם אֱלֹהִים, עָשָׂה אֶת-הָאָדָם.
5 And surely your blood of your lives will I require; at the hand of
every beast will I require it; and at the hand of man, even at the
hand of every man's brother, will I require the life of man.  6 Whoso
sheddeth man's blood, by man shall his blood be shed; for in the image
of God made He man.

Adam has nothing to do with Jews or Judaism. According to the Hebrew Bible, Adam is a placeholder for "first man" or "mankind." This law is a Noahide law which means they are binding on ALL of mankind. We have no evidence from the Torah that God ever intended to replace the Noahide law with another law-system. So if the Torah had not been given, all of the tribes would follow Noahide laws. But since you asked about the Talmud,the Talmud itself even brings down that God made everyone descend from Adam for various moral reasons:

"It was for this reason that man was first created as one person
[Adam], to teach you that anyone who destroys a life is considered by
Scripture to have destroyed an entire world; and anyone who saves a
life is as if he saved an entire world." And also, to promote peace
among the creations, that no man would say to his friend, "My
ancestors are greater than yours." And also, so that heretics will not
say, "there are many rulers up in Heaven." And also, to express the
grandeur of The Holy One [blessed be He]: For a man strikes many coins
from the same die, and all the coins are alike. But the King, the King
of Kings, The Holy One [blessed be He] strikes every man from the die
of the First Man, and yet no man is quite like his friend. Therefore,
every person must say, “For my sake ‎the world was created.”‎

Source: Sanhedrin 5:4 "Anyone who saves a life is as if he saved an entire world": Jewish life or any life?
Please note that the above source is Sanhedrin 5:4. Some manuscripts quote the Mishnah as having "saved one Israelite soul," but if you follow the link you will see this is unlikely to be the original version. The Talmud and Bible doesn't shy away from presenting a universal message, but they spend most of their time dealing with specific Israelite matters. Also the moral message of our tradition can sometimes diverge from our legal tradition.
Sometimes a section Talmud may consider Adam to be specific to Jews (Yevamot 61), but other times it's obvious Adam is being used universally like in Sanhedrin 4:5. Both are true depending on the lens you are currently looking through. Another example is in the 10 commandments, the vast majority of the commentators explain that all the laws there mean for Jews only, and that "your neighbor" means your fellow Israelites. But if you ask if it's okay for a Jew to covet his gentile neighbors wife any religious Jew with any convictions will say no and reference the 10 commandments.
The Bible's moral message is clear. Anyone who murders another human will have their blood shed, whether by man's court, animal's court, or God's court. We Jews learn not to murder any human from this verse. Whether or not a later Talmudic court feels they have the authority to give the death penalty over different types of murder is a separate issue.

That reference in Sanhedrin has another girsa of "anyone who saves a life of Yisroel..."

@Awtsmoos--עצמות Yes that is why I mentioned manuscripts

But manuscripts aren't always authoritative. Also I don't see any reference to manuscripts currently in the answer

If you can provide a proof from Ethiopian Jews you are free to do so. But this is Judaism Stackexchange. The Samaritans and Karaites are not part of Judaism and in fact are considered apikorsus, heretical, for their rejection of the Oral Tradition.

Regarding Sanhedrin 4:5: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/74049/anyone-who-saves-a-life-is-as-if-he-saved-an-entire-world-jewish-life-or-any

Why did you quote this URL?

@KennyXiong Karaites are considered Jews by Ovadia Yosef. I myself consider all forms of ancient Israelitism to be authentic whether it's Ethiopian, Samaritan, Egyptian Karaites, etc. Rabbinic Judaism doesn't get to claim ownership over every legitimate interpretation of the Tanakh. Not even Saadia Gaon or Ibn Ezra believed such a thing

Source? Rambam classes anyone who denies the Torah and rabbinic interpretations as an apikoris. Seeing that the Karaites reject all Oral Traditions, why not include Christians as part of Judaism if you want to blur the lines, G-d forbid.

@KennyXiong The Karaites don't reject the whole oral tradition. They reject what they don't think is true. If they would've rejected everything, they wouldn't have gotten as popular as they did in history. The Rambam is entitled to his opinion and I won't claim to know more than him. But I disagree with him in more than one place.

In relation to Sanhedrin 4:5 please see my answer at https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/74049/anyone-who-saves-a-life-is-as-if-he-saved-an-entire-world-jewish-life-or-any which includes His conclusions were clear-cut: the original version of the “Whoever saves a life” precept was the one without the limiting phrase of “in Israel,” which was a later interpolation

@Awtsmoos--עצמות Thank you. I mentioned manuscripts in a comment and so I've incorporated it into my answer. and I've incorporated a lot from the other comments here as well.

@Aaron unfortunately for your opinion, he's an authoritative codifier of law who bases his opinion on the most well-preserved tradition without which we cannot even understand the performance of simple mitzvot like Tefillin and Shabbat. His words are based accurately on the Gemara “Because he has despised the word of the Lord”; this is a reference to an epikoros, who treats the word of God with contempt. lternatively, one can explain: “Because he has despised the word of the Lord”; this is a reference to one who interprets the Torah inappropriately." (Sanehdrin 99a)

@KennyXiong I quote the Rambam regularly as he is our biggest codifier since Moses/Ezra. But  Rambam says a lot of the stories in Tanakh are actually dreams. Does that mean until the rest of time we have to interpret all our biblical stories as being dreams?

What is your source?

The answer thanks to Rosend is in a Mechilta:
The Torah prohibits a Jew from murdering non-Jews. It is derived from a commentary on Exodus (20:14), ‘when one party schemes against another and kills through treachery, you shall take that person from My very altar to be put to death.’ The Mechilta, Nezikin (4:18) says that “אִישׁ”, ish, man, refers to gentiles. Therefore, premeditated murder of gentiles is directly prohibited by the Torah. Such sins warrant death which cannot be overridden by the pursuit of a positive commandment, if one even exists in such a case.
